# Ubuntu cloud images using qemu/kvm are not properly startin ssh service

Tags: ssh, virtual-machine, qemu, kvm

Today, I have been experiencing a weird problem when starting a cloud-img based VM using qemu/kvm.  Apparently SSH service is not starting properly in the guest, and I cannot access the VM. This is what I see in the logs:

```
See 'systemctl status ssh.service' for details.
[  OK  ] Started Dispatcher daemon for systemd-networkd.
[  OK  ] Stopped OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
[FAILED] Failed to start OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
See 'systemctl status ssh.service' for details.
[  OK  ] Stopped OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
[FAILED] Failed to start OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
See 'systemctl status ssh.service' for details.
[  OK  ] Started Snap Daemon.
Starting Wait until snapd is fully seeded...
[  OK  ] Stopped OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
[FAILED] Failed to start OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
See 'systemctl status ssh.service' for details.
[  OK  ] Stopped OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
[FAILED] Failed to start OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
See 'systemctl status ssh.service' for details.
[  OK  ] Stopped OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
[FAILED] Failed to start OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
```

Also, if I try to log in using serial TTY, I am not able to log in using the credentials I have previously specified using `cloud-localds`.

It is something I have never experienced in years, but this came up today. I tried with different Ubuntu cloud images, different host machines... But nothing, the problem persists.

Does someone have any clue about what is going on and perhaps shed some light on it?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Stack Overflow is for questions about software development. This question would be more appropriate at [unix.se].